# Angular Scope Directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

## *Angular Structural Question*

I am new to angular.js and am just wondering how to go about performing a certain situation.

So basically, what I have got is a container:

```
<div ng-controller="ContainerController">
  <container></container>
</div>
```

And the container controller and directives.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ContainerController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ContainerDirectives.js"></script>
```

Now the directives replaces the `<container>` tag with an example html: `<example>{{ data }}</example>`

Now within the scope of the ContainerController I have defined data as a string. (This is all example purposes). However when the directive accesses replaces it, it is unable to find the variable, due to scope.

The reason that this happens is because the `ContainerDirective` script's scope is not within the `ContainerController` scope. Meaning it is unable to access the variable.

Im just not sure on structure practices for these kinds of situations. Where do I put everything so the `ContainerDirective` can access the `ContainerController` scope.

I hope i have explained everything good enough

## EDIT:

Test.js

```
(function(){

    angular.module('test', []);

})();
```

TestController.js

```
(function(){

angular
    .module('test')
    .controller('TestController', [
        '$scope',
        TestController
    ]);

function TestController($scope) {
    $scope.test = 'test';
}

})();
```

TestDirective.js

```
(function(){

angular.module('test').directive('test', function () {
    return {
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'src/test/view/test.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        }
    };
});
})();
```

test.html

```
<example><a href="abc/{{test}}">ClickMe</a></example>
```

index.html - body

```
<body ng-app="App" layout="row" ng-controller="TestController as page">
<test></test>

<script src="src/test/Test.js"></script>
<script src="src/test/TestController.js"></script>
<script src="src/test/TestDirective.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    angular
          .module('App', ['test']);
</script>
</body>
```

*For reasons I have renamed certain variables and deleted a lot of data, but this is the core, and I am struggling to see anything wrong with this.*

**Error: [$interpolate:noconcat] Error while interpolating: abc/{{test}}
Strict Contextual Escaping disallows interpolations that concatenate multiple expressions when a trusted value is required.**

Comment: Have you read angular docs ? directives parameters are very well explained

Comment: I actually just realised the main difference between my code and those of example codes are they I am using a main module, which includes a sub module. This sub module contains the directive.

Comment: From your updated answer you can't use `<a href="abc/{{test}}">ClickMe</a>` but instead you have to use `<a ng-href="abc/{{test}}">ClickMe</a>` If you want details on why check this link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Comment: Did you try to use controller not with "as" syntax?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what was wrong in the end. Basically angular wont allow iframe of another location to be printed unless you first:

- Give them the full url.
- Then allow external url as a trusted website.

TO do this I had to basically add:
**in the Test.js**

```
angular.module('test', []).config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist($sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist().concat([
        'http://www.test.com/**'
    ]));
});
```

This basically took my whitelist and concatinated the new url to it.

Then inside **test.html**:

```
<example><iframe ng-src={{src}}></iframe></example>
```